# Trying to qualify our software, made with WiX Toolset, in MS Platform Ready program

Tags: c#, service, wix, uninstallation

Input from someone who had to qualify an application for being a Microsoft Gold Partner would be **especially** welcome here.

We are running our software through [Microsoft Platform Ready Test Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41676). Its installer was made with the [latest stable version](http://wixtoolset.org/releases) of WiX. The gist of the test is, while the tool is running, you install, run, and uninstall your application and the Test Tool says whether it's behaving well or not. It fails the test because of leftover files and registry keys, but I haven't a clue how we could possibly clean those up reliably.

**EDIT:** this is the application in question: https://github.com/modulogrc/modSIC

Our software sets up a Windows service, which is correctly removed on uninstall. The offending leftover files are like this:

- Under the logged-in user's Local\Temp directory, four DLLs with 8-character random names (different at each install) and many .tmp files with names starting with "wbk" (and one starting with "vgx")
- A lot of .rbf files under C:\Config.Msi
- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\{a very long name}
- Another long-named file under the user's AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches directory -- and under some other user's, too. (That other user wasn't doing anything while I was testing)
- Many under C:\Users\Public\Documents\MPR -- well, those ones are left by the Test Tool itself, and I suppose we can justify that with a waiver when certifying.

The offending registry keys:

- Many under HKU{Various IDs} under folders named "MuiCache"
- Many under HKU{Various IDs} under folders named "UserAssist"
- These intriguing ones, also under HKU{various IDs}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion:

  `ImmersiveShell\StateStore\ItemsStateStoreLastWrite
  UFH\SHC\8
  Explorer\GlobalAssocChangedCounter`
- Many under HKU{Some ID}\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\Microsoft.Windows.ControlPanel
- SessionIdHigh and SessionIdLow, under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\RNG\Seed
- The ones below, and the same thing with CurrentControlSet instead of ControlSet001 (it's a link, I believe)

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\FastCache\Data\Volatile
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\MUI\StringCacheSettings\StringCacheGeneration
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session`

The files left under the MPR folder tells me the Test Tool does complain about things it shouldn't, so I'm inclined to submit the app anyway. But if there's something, anything I could ameliorate with tweaks in the WiX project's Product.wxs file (some of the other criteria of the MPR test were indeed met by changing it), I'm all ears.

Comment: Sounds like a broken scanner tool.  If your installer has no custom actions and passes validation, it's probably 99% properly written.  I'd have to review to know for sure.

Comment: Our app is open-source, I had forgotten to post the link: https://github.com/modulogrc/modSIC

Comment: Is there anywhere to download the MSI? I Don't feel like cloaning your repos and trying to figure out how to build it.  BTW, I think your domain has expired and been lost.

Comment: Wait a sec... here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15643089/Modulo.Collect.Service.msi

Comment: We're in the process of rebuilding the site.